# Sideload UWP app : [Error] SignTool Error: Access is denied

Tags: c#, uwp, sideloading

To make a sideload UWP application, 
I tried this step ( Step 1 only )
https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-windows-and-windows-phone/how-to-sideload-uwp-applications

but VisualStudio 2017 show this error. WHy ?
My application is a simple UWP application with a button only. ( as test ).

```
SignTool Error: Access is denied.
SignTool Error: An error occurred while attempting to sign: D:\local\MyDevelop2\TestStudy\TestUWP\TestUWP\bin\x86\Release\TestUWP_1.0.0.0_x86.appx  TestUWP
```

I thoutht without signature, We can make sideload application.

Windows 10 : version 1703, OS build 15063.483

How to fix it ?

```
1>  TestUWP -> D:\local\MyDevelop2\TestStudy\TestUWP\TestUWP\bin\x64\Release\TestUWP.exe
1>  Starting .NET Native compilation
1>  Processing application code
1>  Computing application closure and generating interop code
1>  Generating serialization code
1>  Compiling interop code
1>  Cleaning up unreferenced code
1>  Generating native code
1>  Generating fixups for native code
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(3755,5): error APPX1204: 'D:\local\MyDevelop2\TestStudy\TestUWP\TestUWP\bin\x64\Release\TestUWP_1.0.5.0_x64.appx' の署名に失敗しました。SignTool Error: Access is denied.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(3755,5): error APPX1204: SignTool Error: An error occurred while attempting to sign: D:\local\MyDevelop2\TestStudy\TestUWP\TestUWP\bin\x64\Release\TestUWP_1.0.5.0_x64.appx
1>
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(3755,5): error APPX1204:
```

**Update1** : Virus software changed to OFF. Situation is same.

**Update2** : I tried to run again with Verbose mode of compiler. but NO other error message.

**I need solution** : ​I tried to re-install VS2017, but Situation is same. but My other PC can make package without problem. WIndows version is same.. then, Can you tell me How to un-install everything perfectly ? I want to re-set up from beginning.

**------------- I need still help or idea -------------------**

**Update3**
I can not re-install OS.. but I tried another test.

- 1st PC : This VS2017 make bad project file Which can not make a "Sideload Package".
- 2nd PC : This VS2017 can make "Sideload Package" without problem.

I copied the project file from 1st PC to 2nd PC. and on 2nd PC, I tried to make "Sideload Package".. but It failed with 2nd PC. **Wow. it's strange.**

I upload 2 package that I made by 2 PC.
https://github.com/bidasknakayama/SideloadApp

**Update4**
On 2nd PC, I delete "App1_TemporaryKey.pfx" and re-make it. but Package build was failed with same error.

( I translated log message from Japanese to English )

```
1>------ Build start: Project: App1_onBadPC, 構成: Release x86 ------
1>  App1_onBadPC -> F:\MyDevelop\testStudy\App1_onBadPC\App1_onBadPC\bin\x86\Release\App1_onBadPC.exe
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(2007,5): warning APPX0104: Certification file 'App1_onBadPC_TemporaryKey.pfx' can not found
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(2007,5): warning APPX0102: Signature specified by project '922C5A3385C58D83B357F01ED0DB092F79957A7E' can not find certification by certification store. Please specify effective signature.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(2007,5): warning APPX0107: can not use the certification file for this specified certificaiton.  go http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=241478 PLease refer.
1>  Starting .NET Native compilation
1>  Processing application code
1>  Computing application closure and generating interop code
1>  Generating serialization code
1>  Compiling interop code
1>  Cleaning up unreferenced code
1>  Generating native code
1>  Generating fixups for native code
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(3755,5): error APPX0104: Certificaiton file 'App1_onBadPC_TemporaryKey.pfx' が見つかりません。
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(3755,5): error APPX0102: プロジェクトで指定された拇印 '922C5A3385C58D83B357F01ED0DB092F79957A7E' can not find certification by certification store. Please specify effective signature.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(3755,5): error APPX0107: can not use the certification file for this specified certificaiton.  go http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=241478 Please refer.
========== Build: 0 Success、1 Fail、0 Update、0 スキップ ==========
========== Package: 0 Good end、3 failed ===========
```

**Update 5**

I tried to re-install Windows SDK . but It does not resolve this issue. As test, I remove SDK folder and re-install SDK. but No change... :(

** Update 6 **
I found one thing. When I started this Windows 10 OS, it was a local account for login. and I switched to Microsoft account. As test I go back to local account. the  error "SignTool Error: Access is denied" was resolved !! but There is lot of other error. I re-install VS, SDK . but Now, I can not compile empty project only. It's broken perfectly. Microsoft is still poor. They can not control privilege for own system.

**Update 7 !!**

I bought new PC and make UWP applicaiton. First , There is no problem. but Now I got same error !!. It's crazy development tool.

```
  'D:\develop\visualstudio2\shinwatec\Bg7Uwp1\Bg7Uwp1\bin\x86\Release\Bg7Uwp1_1.0.1.0_x86.appx' Signature failed. SignTool Error: Access is denied.
SignTool Error: An error occurred while attempting to sign: D:\develop\visualstudio2\xxx\Bg7Uwp1\Bg7Uwp1\bin\x86\Release\Bg7Uwp1_1.0.1.0_x86.appx   Bg7Uwp1
```

Comment: Refer [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/f25939fb-c48c-4bd0-938e-6a0afbd2dca0/signtool-error-an-unexpected-internal-error-has-occurred?forum=toolsforwinapps)

Comment: it does not resolve the issue. Unfortunately. I tried to re-install VS2017. Situation was same.

Comment: Have you tried [Manual app packaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/manual-packaging-root)?

Comment: No.... VS2017 has good menu to make a package for SideLoading...I do not want to use Manual command because I do not know what command should I do ...

Comment: I tried this command.  "Signtool -f ../../../App8_TemporaryKey.pfx -fd SHA256 -v ./App8_1.0.0.0_x64.appx"     Small windows dialog is open and disappear ( I can not see what is display ). and Powershell does not show any error.

Comment: According to your description, there might be something wrong with your environment. A clean OS install should fix this issue.

Comment: yes, You are right. I thought so, I am planing to buy another PC for build only. I can not clean install current PC.    ......................    but I want to leave last comment to the world , " Microsoft is poor developer ! "